# File and directories permissions linux

Tags: linux, file, permissions, directory

Is is possible to simultaneously:

- Allow a user to manage and create **files** on folders and
- Forbid him to create, rename and delete **folders**?

On linux

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20104/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-deletion-of-certain-files-from-user-owned-directory

Comment: @JoaoVitorino tks, but i think that it doesnt solve my question, because that link only prevent the deletion of *certain files* on a folder. My issue is to not being able to delete *all folders* on a directory (these folders could be created any time by the "owner"). am i wrong?

Comment: ZFS *might*, with some combination of `deny` for `delete_child` and `add_subdirectory` combined with `allow` for `add_file` and `delete`, as long as you can set proper ACL inheritance.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/819-5461/gbacb.html#gbaay